# проект не подключается к MySQL из laradock в проекте Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laradock

есть `laravel` проект который должен подключаться к базе данных mysql. базу данных я использую из laradock (docker). настроил окружение но `php artisan migrate` выдает ошибку подключения к бд.

**`.env` подключения в проекте**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=spectech
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

**`.env` в настройке окружения laradock**

```
### MYSQL #################################################

MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

лог MySQL сервера laradock-а [выглядит так](https://pastebin.com/VRiB3AcX)

upd: я могу подключиться к mysql в том же [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) используя тот конфиг который в .env проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"проблема" в том, что мне не сразу пришло в голову то что `php.ini` нужно отдельно настраивать внутри окружения laradock. и так если у вас в конфигах подключения все верно и именно проект не может подключиться к бд. то скорее всего решение такое:

1. зайдите в рабочее окружение laradock (workspace)(в одной директории с laradock пишем):
   `docker-compose exec workspace bash`
2. найдите файл `php.ini` в этом окружении ( у меня путь был такой `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` **ВНИМАНИЕ** в папке `php` есть папки с разными версиями `php` перед тем как менять **узнайте какую версию php использует ваш проект**. у меня это 7.4 поэтому иду туда. затем откройте файл `php.ini`:
   `cd /etc/php/7.4/`
   `nano php.ini` или любым другим редактором
3. найдите следующую строку в этом файле `;extension=pdo_mysql` (если у вас не подключается бд postgres. там есть `;extension=pgsql` и  `;extension=pdo_pgsql`). и раскомментируете ее. `;extension=pdo_mysql => extension=pdo_mysql` (уберите `;`)
4. выходим из окружения и перезагружаем контейнеры laradock
   `exit`
   `docker-compose restart`